# MYSQL - Search words in multiple coumns

Tags: php, mysql, search

I want to make a search tool for my website.

if i search for a phrase i want it to search multiple columns

for example if i search dewalt drill and the title has the works dewalt power drill i want it to come up.

also if i search dewalt drill and the tile has dewalt and the description has drill i want it to come up.

but all words of the search must be contained in any combination of fields.

can someone help me with the query?

Currently:

```
{Select * from products where sku like '%{$searchwords}%' or title like '%{$searchwords}%' or desc like '%{$searchwords}%}
```

Comment: You need to escape `%` and `_` characters using `addcslashes`, otherwise those will be treated as wildcards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your table is myisam you can create a [fulltext](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html) index then use in boolean mode

to add the key:

`alter table products ADD FULLTEXT (sku, title, desc)`

then your query would be:

```
 $searchwords = join(' +', explode(' ', $searchwords));

 $query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE MATCH (sku, title, desc) AGAINST ('{$searchwords}' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

Comment: obviously you need to make sure you are correctly escaping searchwords

Answer (score 1):

Your probably want [`FULLTEXT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html) searching (starting with MySQL 5.6, this is also available for InnoDB tables). You can require all words with [`BOOLEAN MODE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html).